# Body top-margin issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with a common website template of mine:
http://www.radonsystems.net/newsite/

That space between the top and the first div: navbar.

I can't seem to get rid of it, because I don't know why it's there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an un-ordered list inside your navbar div which still has margin properties.  If you add `margin-top: 0;` to the class or style for that UL the top space will disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your CSS definition for `#navtabs`:

```
#navtabs
{
    /* get rid of the top margin */
    margin-top:0;
}
```

To find the issue I used [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It's a fantastic tool. Once you get used to it you could find this type of problem in about 30 seconds. I really recommend trying it out.

Comment: Thanks :). I've grown to use Firebug :)